# Is there anything like "set -x" in python

Tags: python, debugging

I'd like to run my python script in such a way that every line is printed as it is executed (for debugging purposes), like how you can add `set -x` to a bash script. Is this possible? If not, what other strategies are there for debugging python that don't involve adding log lines everywhere? I usually use pdb but this isn't always suitable for time sensitive applications eg networking.

Comment: You can use PyDev in Eclipse and Debug in Eclipse.

Comment: Run it line-by-line using [*bpython*](http://bpython-interpreter.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`trace` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/trace.html).

```
$ python -m trace -t myscript.py | grep myscript.py
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this doesn't have a huge overhead.